# ExtJS 6 -- autofit grid column header text

Tags: extjs

Is there a way I can set the columns width to match the width of the column text?  The user can resize the columns to see the content if needed, but I want the full header text to be showing at least, even if the column content isnt.

thanks

Comment: I don't think so. I believe you have to implement this on your own using [`Ext.util.TextMetrics`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.util.TextMetrics.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it should be possible. You can call the method [**autoSize()**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#method-autoSize) on the column.
You can combine it with the [minWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-minWidth) and [maxWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-maxWidth).

I have found [this example](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262891-Auto-fit-column-widths-instead-of-having-fix-widths&p=967606&viewfull=1#post967606) on the Sencha forums for Ext 4.2 so it should be very similar for Ext 6.2:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  width: 150, autoSizeColumn: true },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', width: 150, autoSizeColumn: true, minWidth: 150 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', width: 150 }
    ],
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            refresh: function(dataview) {
                Ext.each(dataview.panel.columns, function(column) {
                    if (column.autoSizeColumn === true)
                        column.autoSize();
                })
            }
        }
    },
    width: 450,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```